# Is there a way to reopen last windows when you launch TextMate in Lion?

Tags: macos, textmate

I know TextMate isn't Lion optimised, but is there any way to do this?

Comment: Just wait for TextMate 2.0 to be released :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest build of [TextMate 2](https://github.com/textmate/textmate) does this!

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the [troubleshooting section](http://wiki.macromates.com/Troubleshooting/Lion) you can achieve this by entering the following into your Terminal.app:

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool NO
```

Comment: It works for single files, but not for projects that I created by drag and dropping folders. Does it work for you?

Comment: I tested this with Folders and it doesn't work here either.